# Till death do WE part

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subject-verb-inversion

I understand the meaning of "till death do us part". I even understood why *do* is not *does*.

However, in the song *Love Spent* by Madonna, the following lyrics occur:

> You played with my heart
>   **Till death do we part**
>   That's what you said

and a quick Google search shows that this phrase is used sometimes instead of "till death do us part" in wedding vows and the like.

My questions are:

1. Isn't *we* only used as the subject of a sentence?
2. How can this unusual usage be justified? Does it make sense at all?
3. Does it mean the same as "till death do *us* part" or does it have a different connotation?

Comment: Read it as "till death do[es] part us."

Comment: "Till death do we part"? Sounds like "We will be apart until death"

Comment: To be honest, even "til death do us part" is pretty weird too. What does it mean to *do someone part* ?

Answer (score 12):

Despite the superficial similarity between "Till death do us part" and "Till death do we part", I believe that the structures of these lines are quite different. In this kind of poetic construction word order is typically thrown out of the window in order <sub><sup>(haha!)</sup></sub> to achieve a more pleasing metre or rhyme. This means that we need to look harder at the words to get a sense of what is happening.

In the traditional line, "us" must be the object of "do part", meaning that we need "death" to be the subject. The line can be roughly interpreted as "until death separates us". The line has the form of a conjunction introducing an independent clause and continues a sentence that began in a previous line.

In the song lyric, "we" is the subject. This means that "death" is not and must be something else. Our options seem to be either: that "death" is the object of "part", as in "until we slice Death in two"; or that "part" takes an intransitive sense in "we do part", leaving "death" to form a prepositional phrase with "until". If "until" is forming a prepositional phrase then it is not also a conjunction, meaning that we also have an unwritten full stop at the end of the preceding line. Without presuming to know the mind of the songwriter, this line should probably be interpreted as the full sentence: "We part ways until death."

Answer (score 7):

If “Till death do us part” sounds a trifle odd to the 21st-century ear that is because it is an Early Modern English phrase, from the [Form for the Solemnization of Matrimony](http://justus.anglican.org/resources/bcp/1662/marriage.pdf) in the Church of England’s *Book of Common Prayer.* The original form there is actually “Till death us do part.” The form “Till death do we part” would literally mean that you and I are parting company, never to meet again unless and until we encounter one another in some afterlife. That is probably not the meaning that the pop-song lyricist had in mind, but I agree with Tristan about disposable pop music, so perhaps the term *mind* is here hyperbolic.

Comment: Missing syntax on the _very forgiving_ interpretation aside, here's some internet points for the laugh on the closing remark.

Comment: _Do_ is subjunctive, for an irrealis (counter-factual) condition.

Comment: Thank you all for participating. Actually, what I was suspecting is that in this phrase a kind of inversion takes place. "Till death do we part" would stand for "We [are] part[ing] till death does (happens)". and such weird syntax was used to resemble "till death do us part" which means contrary. Then I thought, isn't too much for one line, so I asked you ))

Comment: @Pablo Inversion of _we part_ in Modern English is _do we part_, with _do_-support, so your extrapolation is not quite right. It's not “till death does”: it's just an inverted form of “until death, we part”.

Comment: Ask Madonna!........................

Answer (score 7):

Nobody really has the sense of this yet. In

> Till death do us part

*us* is the object of the verb *part*.

Write it another way to make it clearer:

> Till death do part us

Now, why is there a *do* there instead of a *does*? Because it is not an indicative but a subjunctive statement. Another way to say that would be

> Till death should [or might, or could, or may] part us

Comment: Sorry, but I think you've misunderstood the question. The question is why the phrase “Till death do we part” (which is how it appears in the song _Love Spent_ by Madonna) works and what it means; it's not about the standard phrase “till death do us part”.

Comment: I'm with @JanusBahsJacquet (whose edit makes the question much clearer). But this answer does nicely explain the usual phrase. Indeed, I have seen wedding ceremonies where the verbiage has been changed to "till death parts us", presumably to be more accessible to modern ears.

Comment: Seems to me that the answer is a combination of the above, and the fact that it's now an unusual phrasing giving rise to "death do we part" as a hypercorrection; putting a nominative pronoun in front of the verb instead of an objective without paying attention to what had been said or what was now said.

Comment: @Jon I don't think so. Madonna herself co-wrote both this song and a previous song of her own, which is titled _Till Death Do Us Part_. The phrase is such a ubiquitously known one, perhaps especially among Americans, that I don't think misparsing or analogy really has much sway here: it's simply a unit to most people.

Comment: The "we" form is a unit?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: If your extensive revision does in fact point us toward the truth, then this question is off topic (interpretation of song lyrics). Voting to close.

Comment: Also, if I misunderstood the question as given, so did Brian.

Comment: @JonHanna No, the _us_ form is a unit, I would say, to the extent that people are not likely to analogically create by-forms like _till death do we part_.

Comment: @Robusto How can a question asking how a pronoun is used grammatically, and whether a particular phrasing written by a native speaker is grammatically justifiable be about interpreting song lyrics? Granted, the third subquestion (which was added by KitFox in her edit) could be seen as veering off in that direction; but not the first two.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to know for sure what Madonna meant with this phrasing. In the context of the lyrics the ordinary "Till death do us part" would make sense, so it's possible she made a mistake.

Alternately, "till death do we part" could be a sort of reversal of the marriage vow, separating from somebody forever, as in "we'll be apart from now on until we die". So it could be a sort of kiss-off.

My own impression is that it sounds more like the former, and Madonna simply sings "we" instead of "us" as either a mistake or simply because it sounded better.

Answer (score -3):

The structure of the phrase is

{till death} do {we part}

not

{till death} {does part} us

The phrase is a sequential/algorithmic logic in expressing the idea:
*We part ways, but not until we die.*

In modern linguistics there are two classes of languages

- analytic
- synthetic

There is a 3rd class which modern linguistics based on European language familiarity seems to be proudly unaware of.

- algorithmic

This class of languages reflects the primordial and primitive ideas of sequence of events. One such language is biblical Hebrew (and hence, Phoenician and ancient Aramaic as well as proto-Arabic). Perhaps primitive humans saw the raw nature as time, in its non-abstract form, just as in the reality of modern Physics, where time is actually due to the sequencing of events. Unfortunately Biblical scholars have been blindly attempting to enforce modern (meaning younger than 2000 years old) European language constructs they are familiar with, on languages that carry the primitive vestiges of at least 3000 years old.

In an algorithmic language structure, you establish the state of a subject sequentially.

1. till death

then

2. we do part

You do not not say *us do part* rather than *we do part*, would you?

Comment: Which is why I doubt the Christian gospels are actually 2000 years old. Unlike biblical Hebrew, their Greek manuscripts are nearly devoid in algorithmic structure. I would expect any literature of 2000 years old to retain a large amount of algorithmic language structure.

Comment: But then, I have never studied the supposed 2300 year old manuscripts of Socrates/Plato to know perhaps that Greek was already an advanced modern language at that time. Or were they transcribed at a later date? But anyway, shouldn't Koine Greek, being street-level Greek express some form of algorithmic pidgin structure?

Comment: As I understand it, the line comes from the Book of Common Prayer, not the Bible itself. The "sequential" nature is also doubtful as the line has transitioned from "Till death us depart" -> "Till death us do part" -> "Till death do us part".

Comment: The people who extracted it from the prayer book had a malapropic inspiration and defaulted into primitive thought patterns and henced algorithmized the language structure.

Comment: Not sure this is an appropriate line of reasoning for ELU. I'm sure there are other places for it.

Comment: There are languages today that use the algorithmic structure, even when speaking in the past. e.g., Yesterday I come home, I eat, I sleep and then I will dream.

Comment: Anything, that explains and give light to a question is "appropriate" to the question. The intent is to answer the question, not to adhere to whether it falls into the domain of ELU. The question should be, "does the question fall into the domain of ELU", not if the answer.