# Why is it "Till death do us part" and not “...does…”

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, subjunctive-mood

Why is the verb "do" used in the phrase, Till death do us part, and not "does"?

I also looked in The Free Dictionary, but it didn't explain why

> **[till death do us part](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/till+death+do+us+part)**
>   A common phrase used in wedding ceremonies indicating that the marriage bond is be intended to last until death. Taken from the marriage liturgy in the Anglican Communion's Book of Common Prayer, the phrase refers to the fact that marriage is seen in the Christian faith as insoluble except by the death of one of the partners. (Also worded as "**till death us do part**," which is how it is written in the Book of Common Prayer.)

Comment: Robusto's answer to the following question says it is subjunctive, which seems right to me: [Till death do WE part](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/216571/77227)

Comment: Also related: [Could the sentence “Not even death can do us part” be considered correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174908/could-the-sentence-not-even-death-can-do-us-part-be-considered-correct)

Comment: Your question might be kept open, there is an older question which asks the same thing, if you ask: "*Why is the verb "do" used in the phrase? Why isn't it*: ***Til death parts us***?" But I leave that decision up to the OP.